# Summation of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Write down the sum of $\displaystyle \sum_1^{2N} n^3$ in terms of $N$, and hence find:
$1^3 - 2^3 + 3^3 - 4^3 + \cdots - (2N)^3$ in terms of $N$, simplifying your answer.

I found this to be $n^2(2n+1)^2$ but the next part is not making sense to me.

Why is the general term of this sum $-(2N)^3$, where it doesn't work for N=0 etc?

thanks

Comment: what do you mean? The general term of this sum is not $-(2N)^2$. And what do you mean by "where it doesn't work for $N=0$ etc"?

Comment: I thought that the last term in the sum was the general term?

like Sum = 1 + 2 + 3 + .... + n then the general term was n?

Comment: The last term in the series is not $-(2N)^2$, either.

Comment: In a finite series like this, what is meant by the $-(2N)^3$

Comment: It's the last term in the sum.

Comment: But you just said it wasnt?

Comment: Please read *carefully* what I wrote. $-(2N)^2$ is not the same thing as $-(2N)^3$, is it? Meanwhile, I see you have edited out the $-(2N)^2$, which was a good thing to do, even though it makes nonsense out of some of this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

As
$$
\begin{align}
& \sum_{1\le r\le n}r^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}4 \\[10pt]
& 1^3 - 2^3 + 3^3 - 4^3 + \cdots - (2N)^3 \\[10pt]
& =\sum_{1\le r\le 2N}r^3-2\sum_{1\le r\le N}(2r)^3 \\[10pt]
& =\sum_{1\le r\le 2N}r^3-2\cdot8\sum_{1\le r\le N}r^3 \\[10pt]
& =\frac{(2N)^2(2N+1)^2}4-16\frac{N^2(N+1)^2}4 \\[10pt]
& =N^2\{(2N+1)^2-4(N+1)^2\} \\[10pt]
& =-N^2(4N+3)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, could you please add displaystyle in the fourth line and replace brace with bracket in the last line else my change will add new edition

Comment: This formula gives the wrong answer for $N=1$. Also, I don't think it engages with the question OP is asking (which is understandable, since the question is not).

Comment: How do I write the sum as a summation? what's the general term of the sequence $1^3 -2^3+3^3-4^3+..-(2N)^3$

Comment: @user90771, have you noticed the latest  edition of this answer. The general term is $(-r)^3=-r^3,1\le r\le 2N$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee how do I establish the general term is $(-r)^3$??

Comment: @labbhattacharjee but this doesnt work for r = 1? $(-1)^3$ = -1

Comment: @user90771, sorry for the mistake, it should be $(-1)^{r-1}r^3$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee no problem but how do I establish that this is the general term by just looking at the sequence?

Comment: @user90771, observe that the sign toggles, hence $(-1)^{r-1}$ as the sign is negative for the even terms and positive for the odd terms

Comment: The formula has been edited, and now gives the right answer for $N=1$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee hey, can I ask about this $$(-1)^{r-1}$$, do I always use this when the signs in a series changes? What about $$(-1)^r$$, where would that be used?

Comment: @user90771, if  as the sign is negative for the odd terms and positive for the positive terms as $(-1)^{2m}=1$ and $(-1)^{2m+1}=-1$